# here map PositioningManager.getInstance() singleton null object?

Tags: android, here-api

Issue: `ProjectManager.getInstance();` gives null object, I am clueless I have done the code as below,

**Activity class & Manifest file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="proj.Mobi">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.appid" android:value="WcIOjXKhgYk8" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.apptoken" android:value="XaRs1SILAVi2sw" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.here.android.maps.license.key" android:value="phEpi5ZL3jiNTElgM3ldzrJTeevoNeYY47oE9eSzgJfySv=" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I am creating class of map activity below, I have created the `PositioningManager.getInstance()` it gives null object by Toast popup

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // map embedded in the map fragment
    private Map map = null;
    // map fragment embedded in this activity
    private MapFragment mapFragment = null;

    private PositioningManager positioningManager = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Positioning Manager
        positioningManager = PositioningManager.getInstance();
        if (positioningManager == null) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, " Positioning Null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        // Search for the map fragment to finish setup by calling init().
        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);
        mapFragment.init(new OnEngineInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(
                    OnEngineInitListener.Error error) {
                if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE) {
                    // retrieve a reference of the map from the map fragment
                    map = mapFragment.getMap();
                    // Set the map center to the Vancouver region (no animation)
                    map.setCenter(new GeoCoordinate(12.9172, 77.5738, 0.0),
                            Map.Animation.NONE);
                    // Set the zoom level to the average between min and max
                    map.setZoomLevel(
                            (map.getMaxZoomLevel() + map.getMinZoomLevel()) / 2);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error:" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything that's HERE Maps related needs to happen after initialization. This is applicable for everything related to the HERE MobileSDK.

Try getting the PositioningManager inside your EngineInitListener.onEngineInitializationCompleted (and keep in mind, once you get the instance, you also have to call start on it to receive any events)

Comment: you are right the positioningManager must be intialized with in the EngineInitListener.